# Android ConnectivityManager information

Tags: android, network-programming

I am trying to get a better grip on Android's ConnectivityManager and how it really works under the hood.  Using the API is simple enough but I am looking for something lower level such as when it starts and the dirty details of what its doing in the background.  I can't seem to find a good resource about it.  Everything is just about using the API.

Does anyone understand this or have any resources that they could point me to, website, book, white paper, or otherwise?  I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you posted a particular question someone may be able to help you.  Or you could look at the Android source.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The problem is that I can't even get into it enough to have specific questions.  I was hoping for an overview of how it all goes down.  I am trying to get the source now thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: so you want to understand what the system service is doing? i think that abstraction is in place for a good reason, and unless you plan on hacking your device, there isnt much good reason to go mucking around in the OS. If you are really set on digging around, i would suggest what CaseyB said: look at the Android source code. Besides that, i doubt google is going to explain much beyond their APIs

Comment: Yea I basically want to know more about what it's doing.  So I guess the source is the best place to start.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to close this one out.

Source files are the best way to go on this one.  Java.android.net is the directory that holds all the networking java services.  To look at switching from network to network, however, one would have to look in the native layer.